# Conservation of the area under a curve?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, area

Imagine the function $\Psi(x, t) \in \mathcal C^2(U)$ with $U \subset \mathbb R^2$, obeys the following PDE:
$$
A\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial t^2} +B\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} + C\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} + D\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} + F\Psi = 0
$$
And, also, you want the area under the function $\Psi$ to be conserved:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \; |\Psi(x, t)|^2 \; = 0
$$
I rather use $|\Psi(x, t)|^2$ instead of $|\Psi(x, t)|$, so all the area is positive, and perfectly smooth. Hence:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \; \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\Psi(x, t)|^2 \; = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \; 2 \Psi\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}\; = 0
$$
substituting $\Psi$ and $\partial \Psi / \partial t$, from our differential equation:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \; \Psi\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}\; = 0  \\ \; \\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \; \frac{1}{CF} \left [ A\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial t^2} +B\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} + C\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} + D\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} \right] \left [ A\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial t^2} +B\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} + D\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} + F\Psi \right]\; = 0
$$
Forcing the term inside the integral to be zero, we get two solutions:
$$
A\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial t^2} +B\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} + C\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} + D\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} = 0
$$
$$
A\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial t^2} +B\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} + D\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} + F\Psi = 0
$$
So, any function $\Psi$, that obeys one of these PDEs, has it's area squared, $|\Psi(x, t)|^2$, conserved? Is my line of reasoning wrong? If I'm wrong, how would I approach this? Any hint?

Comment: I'm not sure what the substitution step achieves, since your final system of equations includes $\Psi$ and $\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$ .

Comment: Observe also that enforcing $\Psi \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = 0$ identically (as you implicitly have) means that locally either $\Psi = 0$ or $\Psi$ is constant in time. This of course will mean that the original integral is conserved, but it should be clear that this condition ends up being much too strict. For example, any compactly supported function "moving" from left to right has a constant value for the original integral, but does not satisfy the constraint on the integrand you have imposed.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Yeah, that's right. But how would I impose constant area, even thought the function depends on $t$?

Comment: You could require that $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \|\Psi(x,t)\|^2 dx = 0$. This may be very unsatisfying, but that is usually the best we can do without restrictions on the $\Psi$ we're considering. Requiring a constant integral norm is a highly non-local constraint, so you require some highly non-local information about your function to say anything interesting.